# infix function: how to avoid parentheses around supplied argument

Tags: kotlin, lambda, infix-notation

I have the following infix fun

```
infix fun <T> Boolean.then(lazyValue: () -> T): T?
        = if (this) lazyValue() else null
```

with following use case

```
(index > 0) then { data[index - 1].id }
```

I want to rewrite it as

```
index > 0 then { data[index - 1].id }
```

and avoid parentheses around index > 0. Currently it does not resolve in code.
Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: No, it is basically like asking: Can I remove the parantheses here (1 + 2) * 3 ? No, you can't because that would mean something different.

Comment: Thank you. It seems impossible..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that won't work.

According to the [operator precedence table](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#expressions) in the Kotlin Grammar reference, the precedence of infix function calls, such as `then` in your case, is higher than that of comparison operators `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`.

So without parentheses, an expression like `index > 0 then { ... }` is parsed like `index > (0 then { ... })` and not the other way.